# XML namespaces - default declaration

Tags: xml, namespaces

I have an XML and some struggle understanding how elements are qualified to the namespaces. Unfortunately I could not find a valid answer for my question. I have a small example to make it easier to follow my question (sorry for the German expressions):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Buchempfehlungen xmlns:book="http://aifb.kit.edu/buecher"
xmlns:pub="http://aifb.kit.edu/publisher">
    <Empfehlung>
        <book:Titel>Kleines Handbuch für den Umgang mit Unwissen</book:Titel>
        <book:ISBN>978-3442749775</book:ISBN>
        <Autor xmlns="http://aifb.kit.edu/buecher">
            <Name>Nassim Nicholas Taleb</Name>
            <Geburtsdatum>1. Januar 1960</Geburtsdatum>
        </Autor>
        <Verlag>
            <pub:Name>btb</pub:Name>
            <pub:Ort>München</pub:Ort>
        </Verlag>
    </Empfehlung>
</Buchempfehlungen>
```

Now my question is, to which namespace is the element "Verlag" assigned? Since there is no default-namespace declaration in the root element. But there is a default in the element Autor, which is on the same "level" as "Verlag"

Does this "deeper" default-ns declaration count for the whole document or just it´s descendants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following XPath expression returns the *Verlag* element. Its sibling **Autor** default namespace doesn't affect it. Just its descendants, i.e. **Name** and **Geburtsdatum**, belong to the same default namespace `xmlns="http://aifb.kit.edu/buecher"`.

> XPath

```
/Buchempfehlungen/Empfehlung/Verlag
```

> Output

```
<Verlag>
    <pub:Name>btb</pub:Name>
    <pub:Ort>München</pub:Ort>
</Verlag>
```